# Fitnesse SymbolicLink not working with external link from ant or command line

Tags: ant, command-line, fitnesse

We are trying to create a symbolic link in our fitnesse suite to an external folder. It is working perfectly with URL. But not working with command line or with ant script.

**Following is the URL (Working):**

```
http://localhost:8080/root?responder=symlink&linkName=FitNesseSuite&linkPath=file://FitNesseRoot/TestSuite
```

**Command line (Not working):**

```
java -jar fitnesse.jar -c "root?responder=symlink&linkName=FitNesseSuite&linkPath=file://FitNesseRoot/TestSuite"
```

**Ant script (Not working):**

```
<target name="my_fitnesse_tests">
    <java jar="fitnesse.jar" failonerror="true" fork="true">
        <arg value="-c" />
        <arg value="root?responder=symlink&amp;linkName=FitNesseSuite&amp;linkPath=file://FitNesseRoot/TestSuite" />
        <arg value="-p" />
        <arg value="9234" />
    </java>
</target>
```

**Getting following exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Command
>   specification
>   [root?responder=symlink&linkName=FitNesseSuite&linkPath=file://FitNesseRoot/TestSuite]
>   invalid. Format shold be /cmd or user:pass:/cmd at
>   fitnesse.http.MockRequestBuilder.validate(MockRequestBuilder.java:48)

Please help us to solve this.

Comment: So you are trying dynamically add in the symbolic links as a part of your ant task?  You don't know what they would be in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem, I have solve the problem with the following command:
...&linkPath=file%3A///... ==> change the ":" by "%3A"